# How to extract path from registry key value?

Tags: wix

I want to use the registry key value as the installation path. My key looks like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\CAB Oy\XXXX\bin\XXX_ServiceManager.exe"  -service E:\XXXXName
```

How to extract (using wix) only:

```
C:\Program Files\CAB Oy\XXXX\
```

?

Comment: Custom action only. First, you use `RegistrySearch` to grab the value from registry to the property. Next, you schedule an immediate custom action to take this property and transform it to the form you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wix does not support substring like functions. You need to use a custom action for it. There is no other way.